# I can run my Qt program (C++) in the system tray, but how to remove it from the task bar?

Tags: qt

I could successfully compiled and run a program which has its icon in a system tray.
There is a good example explaining it here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html

**Now is my problem**: When I run my program, its icon is still visible also in the task bar.
How to get rid of this icon from the task bar?

*Why it is important to me? My program will be an alarm-clock, so it should be visible on the Desktop, but it should not be occupying place on the task bar. This is why I decided to place it in the system tray. So, how to get rid of it from the task bar?*

Answer (score 0):

In the example you need to just uncheck the corresponding checkbox, which set the [`visible`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#visible-prop) property to `true` or `false`:

[image: Widget from the example]

Line in the example where the checkbox connects to the property:

```
connect(showIconCheckBox, &QAbstractButton::toggled, 
    trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible);
```

Then you can close the window. The application will be still running because of the line

```
QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Comment: Dear Vladimir, by this uncheck - which you mention - I can hide an icon in the systtem tray. But i want something opposite: I want to hide any info present in a TASK BAR. 
I do not want to occupy taskbar to show a my program which I am planning to run for many months.

So, how to remove an icon and "entry" from the taskbar?

Comment: @JurekGrandBosh in this case you just need close the window of the application

Comment: This works, but...  My program is a fancy clock - which is also an alarm clock. It shows the current time. If I do, what you suggest now, the clock face disappears. This not what I want.  So here is what I want: 
1) clock being shown on my desktop (and constantly running) 
2) I want to have its icon in my system tray
BUT:
I do not want to have any entry on Task Bar.
======

Comment: @JurekGrandBosh try this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/22710/solved-how-to-remove-application-s-button-from-taskbar-for-minimizing-to-tray-with-qt-5

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an answer

The information in the Task Bar about a particular running program  is independent on the system tray information. So to make the program info (and its icon) 'not present' in the task bar - we have to work in a different place: We need to change the attribute of a main window of the program. In this case **it was enough to add  - the following line in a constructor of the program window:**

setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool);

**The tool dialog is a kind of window which information is not "placed" in a task Bar.**
So now it works as I planed.